# Noob needs help calling another class within same project

Tags: java

Hey guys super noob here and I've tired reading other answers to understand this but I just can't figure it out. So I have this class here.

```
public class Testing {
public static void main(String[] args) {

System.out.println("Hello boss awesome");
System.out.println("My name is Luke Duke'm");
}
}
```

I want to call another class I have created into this class to print the current date and time. This is the class I have created to get the date/time.

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class date {
public void main(String args[]) {

TimeZone zone = TimeZone.getDefault();
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat ("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm");
format.setTimeZone(zone);
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
System.out.println(format.format(cal.getTime()));
}
}
```

What do I need to put into the Testing class to call the date class and have it print the date. Sorry for being such a noob but got to learn somehow.

Comment: There's...really nothing from that class that's substantial to put in there.  It'd be the same as instantiating `SimpleDateFormat` there, without any arguments to the constructor though.

Answer (score 0):

Please change the class name date to another one.It is the name of predefined class
  You can  not call main method of other class.So write a userdefined method

```
public class ClassName{

  public getDate() {

   TimeZone zone = TimeZone.getDefault();
   DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat ("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm");
   format.setTimeZone(zone);
   Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
   System.out.println(format.format(cal.getTime()));
  }
}
 public class Testing {    

  public static void main(String[] args) {

   ClassName obj =  new ClassName();
   obj .getDate();

   System.out.println("Hello boss awesome");
   System.out.println("My name is Luke Duke'm");
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an object of date class you have created and try to call the method, to do the job, the method is entitled to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.TimeZone;

    public class Date {
    public void printDate() {

    TimeZone zone = TimeZone.getDefault();
    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat ("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm");
    format.setTimeZone(zone);
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    System.out.println(format.format(cal.getTime()));
    }
    }
```

Create the instance of the above class in the other class as below

```
public class Testing {
public static void main(String[] args) {
Date objdate=new Date();
objdate.printDate();
System.out.println("Hello boss awesome");
System.out.println("My name is Luke Duke'm");
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `date` class change the name of the method to some thing else, like

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class date {
    public void printDate() {

    TimeZone zone = TimeZone.getDefault();
    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat ("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm");
    format.setTimeZone(zone);
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    System.out.println(format.format(cal.getTime()));
    }
}
```

and in main method of your `Testing` class

1. create the object of `date`
2. call the `printDate()` on the created instance of the `date` class

   public class Testing {

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args) {

   System.out.println("Hello boss awesome");
   System.out.println("My name is Luke Duke'm");
   date d = new date();
   System.out.print("date:");
   d.printDate();
   }
   ```

   }